# Opening a pop-up through javascript

Tags: javascript, popup

I am trying to open a new link in a popup window, but its not working.

This is the snippet that I am using for opening the popup

```
function load() {
window.open('../../fbConnect.php','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');
}
```

I am then calling the function `load` .

Can anyone predict whats wrong in my approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May your browser block the popup? I tried to run this code and it worked after I enabled popups.

Answer (score 0):

Open Google Chrome. Press Control-Shift-I to open the Developer Tools. Click the Console Tab. Load the page. Check for JavaScript errors reported in the console. If you find your error, you're done.

Still got nothing? Replace the interior of the load() function with

`alert('Hello!');`

If it works, check your syntax for "window.open". If it fails, check how you are calling `load()`.